# Changes are being lost between TFS changeset checkin

Tags: tfs

I'm finding that a number of my changes are being 'lost' when our contractor performs a check-in.

The general process is as follows:

1. I perform some bug analysis and implement a fix.
2. I then check-in my code.
3. The contractor performs a check-out/check-in at a later date.
4. The changes from the previous changeset (my changes) are lost.

In my view, this is pretty unacceptable, particularly when I'm dealing with application-breaking regressions introduced since the last build.

This has happened at least twice now, and the only thing I can think of is that the contractor is failing to ensure that he has the latest changeset at check-out. Our repo does not allow multiple check-out, and forces get latest on checkout, which makes things so weird (seeing as we both should be working with Server workspaces).

Could there be any other cause of this problem? I don't want to take my concerns to my line manager without being sure I've covered all bases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Get Latest item on check out` is set in the client and not in the repo, which means that your contractor may still be able to checkout the wrong version. They should get merge conflicts upon doing so, but that depends on where they edit (and how they manage such conflicts).

Answer (score 0):

I've seen TFS lose changes this way.  I have yesterday gone to a client site, made changes, checked in, today come back to my office, got the changes (assuming it will merge with my local changes like it usually does), gone to check in just now and I can see in the diff that it's wiped out the client-site changes (obviously ignoring the merge locally).  I checked in just to confirm what I was seeing and yes there was no resolve conflict needed, TFS thought everything was ok, but my modified local file just blatantly overwrote the modified version in TFS effectively discarding the whole client-site change (just like if I'd chosen resolve conflict keep mine - however it never asked me about the conflict or suggested that there was one, just silently lost it)

If you eye-ball the changes before committing you can see that the changes you are making are more than you thought - i.e. the client site changes are effectively being removed and will show as differences - however it's easy to miss this when you are doing it a lot.
I had previously thought to blame coworkers when they skip out my changes this way, but now I've actually seen myself do this to myself I realise the tool is deficient.  Hard to believe but there is obviously something wrong with the way it merges your locally changed file against the 'get latest'.  I'm using a cloud TFS with a flaky network connection sometimes - I'm told this contributes to the issue.

Comment: Indeed, a flaky network problem may contribute to you getting into this state.  If you tried to check out the file and there was some network issue that prevented you from contacting the server, and you were to overwrite the file anyway, then you have made modifications but not checked the file out, and TFS will feel free to overwrite that file.  Do make sure that your files are checked out properly.  Or use local workspaces in TFS 2012 (or newer) that do not require contacting the server to check the file out.

Comment: in the scenario I saw, the file was checked out locally and changed, and then checked-out and changed at a remote location, then checked-in from the remote location, then a get-latest was issued locally and there's no sign that the merge occurred to the local file, it just ignored the remote location changes.  When I explicitly did a diff it showed me the latest version in the repository had the changes and my file didn't, but it was quite happy with that scenario and allowed me to checkin my file without the changes effectively reversing the remote site's changes.